# Headings and TOC in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2010

I created a table of contents that updates according to the text I mark as "Heading 1" (or "Heading 2" for subchapters etc.). The table of contents works.

But I noticed that the chapter titles (i.e. the text marked as Heading 1) is a bit jumpy. I try to keep chapter titles at the top of a page but they like moving down a few lines on their own and when I correct them by removing spaces above them they jump onto the page before.

Is there a way to explain to Word that I want chapter titles at the top of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place each chapter on new section or use page break (Insert > Page Break). To insert a section break in your document, click Page Layout > Page Setup > Breaks. The following panel is split up into page breaks and section breaks.

[image]

Read more about sections in Word 2010 [here](http://www.word-2010.com/microsoft-word-2010-section-break/).